# Why video dimension changes after created from a set of images by FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a set of png images with a dimension of 928x540 pix, and I am trying to create a video based on these images.

Here is the command I am using:

```
ffmpeg -y -r 25 -start_number 0 -i frame%d.png -vf scale=-1:540 -c:v libx264 -crf 0 out.mp4
```

This command is working fine and I could get a video. But the video has a dimension of 928x536. Why it is getting 4pixs smaller even I am controlling with scale filter "scale=-1:540"? Does anyone happen to have the same issue? Thanks a lot.

Here is what I see from the cmd window:
[captured cmd window 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEYbQ.png)
[captured cmd window 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToZ53.png)

output video info:
[output video info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44aTf.png)

Comment: Why apply the scale filter at all?

Comment: By applying the scale filter, it is simply because I see the first video with a different dimension. Actually, whether I apply the scale filter or not, it will end up with the same dimension of 928x536. Don't know why.

Comment: Copy and paste the complete log.

Comment: Screenshots of the cmd window are attached.

Comment: Maybe Windows is lying... you might try `ffprobe out.mp4`

Comment: That's true. Tried ffprobe out, got a correct dimension of 928x540. Interesting. Why Windows doesn't like 540? Quite weird. Anyway, thank you all for checking this question. @Mark Setchell

Comment: Copy and paste the text [instead of making images of the text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Comment: Actually, I was trying to copy and paste the text. But, the format is very ugly and I didn't figure out how to edit it in a readable way in the post. Probably, it is my first time asking question, I guess I need to learn more rules in this forum.